# SQL Server converting image info to text

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have been trying to convert a column in SQL Server to a `varchar` / `text` format. I am trying as below and didn't see expected output. Can anyone please help?

```
select top 10 
    convert(varchar(max), convert(varbinary(max), JobSpec)) 
from ScheduledJob
```

The column contains data like this: (truncated the two rows as it contains huge lines)

> 0xF9FFFFFF00000000000000000000000000000000260000007B38463642443236342D383838442D313144302D423137462D3230344334463446
>   0xF9FFFFFF00000000000000000000000000000000260000007B38463642443236342D383838442D313144302D423137462D3230344334463446353032307D0000000000000000000000000000000000000000240000004A6F6220547970653A204164642D496

The output from my query:

```
¨   
¨   
¨   
¨     
¨   
¨   
¨   
¨     
¨     
¨
```

Please check and let me know the correct way to convert this into text.

Comment: should work. maybe you need `nvarchar(max)` insted of `varchar(max)`... or try `cast` instead of `convert`...

Comment: What data type is column `JobSpec` ?

Comment: CAST(JobSpec AS VARCHAR(MAX)). Will this work?